# Derivation of integral when the derivation variable is different

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I have this problem that it seems pretty basic, yet complicated for me. I'm trying to differentiate this term with respect to x.

$$\int_{j \in [0,1]} x_j  dj$$

I think it should $$x_j$$ but am not really sure. please help.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Could you please provide more context? Is $x$ a function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with $j\mapsto x_j$?

Comment: Thanks. well, actually am trying to describe an economic problem with it concerning cryptocurrency mining. $$x_j$$ is supposed to be the individual mining power, and the whole integral is the total mining power. $$j$$ stands for individual miners. This is the only context i have regarding this problem.

Comment: And you want to take a derivative w.r.t. $x$ which is a function? Why? Do you want to find what function maximizes (or minimizes) the integral? If so, are the any constraints on $x$?

Comment: am trying to solve a maximizing problem, where $$x_j/\int_{j \in [0,1]} x_j  dj$$ is the share of each miner of the reward. so each miner would maximizes his power $$x_j$$ to get more reward.

Comment: and no, there is no constraints.

Comment: A single miner would have his share maximized if the others don't get anything.

Comment: Actually, your answer helped me to answer a different question. mine needs some reformulations to look little bit logical. but thank you soo much

Comment: You need to think about a exactly what you want to maximize. It should be a single $\mathbb{R}$-valued function.